# Android ZXing barcode scanner not working with HTC Evo 4g Lte

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, htc-android, evo

One of my users is having a problem using the barcode scanner on my app. Basically, it won't scan, it never has.

He is using my app on a HTC Evo 4g Lte.

My app makes use of the ZXing integrated code and this is the first device that has had an issue scanning bacodes.

The only information I have is that he is always scanning in bright light.

I am trying to problem solve this issue remotely so don't have access to logcat output or the device itself.

I have seen from googling on other sites that people have mentioned issues with autofocus and blurry camera photos.

I think this could be one issue where the problem lies.

I have a number of questions:

1) What could be causing the issue? Phone camera, firmware?
2) How should I proceed with the user issue? How can I get them to zero in on the cause so that I can fix it at my desk? 
3) Or has anyone come across this issue before and was able to resolve it?

Thanks. I will update my text here if I find other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly check if autofocus is not required on camera since not all of the devices are supporting it:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Secondly since you are using integrated zxing within your app, you have to check if user already has installed original ZXing Barcode scanner and use that one through Intent and not the embedded one.

Implement ACRA or some similar library which will send logs wherever you define it giving you access to it without having the device itself.

If the app is on the Google Play and app crashes tell your user to tap on the Report in FC dialog which will show you the Stack trace in Google Play developer console.

Comment: Question, should I set <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" /> to false? Do I not need it to scan the barcode? Also, the app has not crashed so I see no reports with a stack trace in the Google Play developer console. Will look into ACRA this afternoon. Thanks

Comment: by setting it to false you will enable the devices with camera which do not support autofocus to use your application. I don't think it would be a problem, but I would have to test the zxing on some devices to be sure.